# How to optimize this user ranking query

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

I have 2 databases (users, userRankings) for a system that needs to have rankings updated every 10 minutes.  I use the following code to update these rankings which works fairly well, but there is still a full table scan involved which slows things down with a few hundred thousand users.

```
mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE userRankings");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO userRankings (userid) SELECT id FROM users ORDER BY score DESC");
mysql_query("UPDATE users a, userRankings b SET a.rank = b.rank WHERE a.id = b.userid");
```

In the userRankings table, rank is the primary key and userid is an index.  Both tables are MyISAM (I've wondered if it might be beneficial to make userRankings InnoDB).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this, it should give you the same effect without needing to build a separate table.   (my MySql is a bit rusty, but this should work OK)

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 ‘rank’, a.id 
from player a, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r 
order by score desc
```

Comment: This just selects the users, and it does indeed select them in their ranking order, how do I use that to update their ranking in a more efficient way than I currently do?

Comment: Why do you need to update the rankings?  If this query returns the data you need, is it really a necessity to physically store the ranking value (which can change frequently).   If your users only need to view the ranked users, just use this query.   Is there some other system that requires an actual ranking table that cannot be replaced with this query?

Comment: I don't just show the total ranking list, I show the ranking for specific users as well as specific ranges of users.

Comment: SET @rownum=0; UPDATE users JOIN (SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rank, id FROM users ORDER BY score DESC) AS o USING(id) SET users.rank = o.rank

Comment: You could also create a view, replacing the a.id with a.* and then query the view, although updating the table one-time as you did above would improve performance over the view...

Answer (score 0):

Which query is it that's actually taking most of the time?  I'll wager it's the third one.

Benchmark your query by converting it to a SELECT:

```
SELECT a.rank, b.rank 
FROM users a, userRankings b
WHERE a.id = b.userid
```

[Explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html) can help you debug how indexes are being used.

**The first thing you should do is drop that old table1,table2 syntax.**  It's difficult to read, and can be very inefficient.  You should always use JOINs.

```
UPDATE users AS a
JOIN userRankings AS b ON a.id = b.userid
SET a.rank = b.rank
```

That may fix your problem right there - hopefully EXPLAIN can help you narrow in on specific issues.  Make sure that both columns (users.id and userRankings.userid) are the exact same type (as in, one of them isn't signed while the other is, for example).

For more help, you would need to post more data (the SHOW CREATE TABLE results for each table, how long each of the queries take when you run them, the number of rows in the tables).

Comment: I used EXPLAIN to see that it wasn't optimized correctly, but I've been unable to find a way to optimize it more effectively.  I tried out doing it with a JOIN as you suggest, but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: All right, so now you have a better defined problem: your query isn't using an index, and you think it should.  To tackle this next step, you should update your question with the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE yourtable` and `EXPLAIN [your select query]`.